# pd.get_dummies syntax error python

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I am getting an error while using pandas get_dummies command. Can someone point out why?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

s = pd.read_csv('kddcup.txt')
t=s.apply(pd.Series.nunique)
print(t.index)
r = s.columns
print(r)

for n in range (0,len(t.index)):
    if t[r[n]] == 1:
        del s[r[n]    

s = pd.get_dummies(s)//getting syntax error error here.
```

[Spyder error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6nrv.png)

Comment: In python, comment are `#`, not `//`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `del s[r[n]` to `del s[r[n]]`. Each opening bracket must have a closing one.

Comment: Of course, I didn't see that. I've been staring at my code for the past hour trying to figure it out. Thanks, man.